# Magnitude of product of symmetric matrix and unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is any symmetric 2 by 2 matrix with eigenvalues -3 and 3 and $\vec{u}$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, what is $||A\vec{u}||$?

Any help would be appreciated, I haven't the slightest idea of how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be done because the eigenvalues have the same magnitude and $A$ is assumed symmetric.

Write $u=c_1 q_1 + c_2 q_2$, where $q_1,q_2$ are orthonormal eigenvectors with eigenvalues $3$ and $-3$ respectively. Use the Pythagorean theorem here to get a representation of $\| u \|$ which you already know is $1$. Then $Au=3 c_1 q_1 - 3 c_2 q_2$. Now use the Pythagorean theorem there to find $\| Au \|$.

Comment: Can you explain the importance of the symmetric part?

Comment: @ejz I used the symmetry to guarantee that the eigenvectors are orthogonal. This result is called the spectral theorem.